# Do mods of stackexchange sites get paid?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Do they get paid? Or is it a volunteer position? Thank you very much for your help. Also please move this to meta since I can't do that.

Comment: So is Bill D suspended from using his coffee mug for a week, as well??

Comment: @TheChaz What does that mean? Bill takes a break?

Comment: I have to admit, every time I look at the title it seems that it said "*Do mods of stackexchange sites get **iPads***".

Comment: I figure it has to do with the scrubbing of comments from the Sticks&Stones meta question. No big deal. I'm an unabashed Bill D fan - that he pisses off so many higher-ups endears him even more to myself!

Comment: @TheChaz So where was this announced?

Comment: @Michael: I was under the impression that punishments are not announced. Our discussing it here might even be against the public idea of propriety.

Comment: @TheChaz I see. You know from a mod?

Comment: @Michael: Something I was looking at had been edited most recently by Bill D, and it showed his rep at 1. That only happens with suspensions, IIRC

Comment: @TheChaz: The mods are coming to terms about a few things right now. There should be a meta post in the next few days from a mod with the details.

Comment: @TheChaz: I see nonnegligible rep for both Bill D and Q, but they both appear to have misplaced their diamonds (at least temporarily).

Comment: @TheChaz I am leaving MSE. I can no longer tolerate the extreme abuse of unilateral moderator powers by Qiaochu Yuan, with full support from SE. Best of luck to everyone.

Comment: @TheChaz, Bill D is a moderator --- who are these "higher-ups" you say he pisses off?

Comment: @Gone: Thank you for your contribution to the betterment of mathematical knowledge in the global online community over the past decades. I hate to see you go. Sincerely,

Comment: @Gerry Bye, it was fun while it lasted. I think your old sci.math comment was right - I take these things far too seriously for some folks. --Bill

Comment: @TheChaz No, that's not the reason - see chat.

Comment: It's all fun and games until some website loses a moderator.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Not the first and sadly probably not the last.

Comment: How come when both Arturo and Zev left the site (within one week) it took people a couple of weeks to notice (and even then there was only one thread pointing out about Arturo, and none about Zev), but when Bill quits everywhere people have to talk about it?

Comment: @Asaf: We've also apparently lost Theo aka t.b. fairly recently, though I have no idea what the underlying reason is. It is a shame, really.

Comment: @Asaf, are you serious? Compare the events surrounding the departures of Arturo and Zev (of which there were none that I'm aware of) with the events surrounding the departure of Bill and see if you can't figure out why so many people (yourself prominent among them!) have to talk about the latter while so few talk about the former.

Comment: @TheChaz: I would like to point you to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6837/9754

Comment: @mixedmath: I'm glad it was you who made that post, Mr. Spade

Comment: @cardinal: This is the second time I see someone say that t.b. left. [His account page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/5363/t-b) seems to say otherwise.

Comment: @joriki: It appears he has changed it within the last few hours. Previously it simply said "gone." :-)

Answer (score 19):

[Community moderators](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) are all volunteers and do not get paid, though we do occasionally send them some swag.

Stack-Exchange-the-Company has a [whole bunch of employees](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) (and we're still growing!), so those of us on the [community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do), developers, and so on, do take a salary.

Comment: I just noticed that the link to the shop.SE site is not working anymore. Does that mean that one cannot buy swag, or is the swag just located at a riddle site for which you need to solve two questions from SE sites and encode their answers into a URL...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Unfortunately [we had to close the store](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store). Swag's still available for events, conferences, leading users, etc, but we don't sell it anymore.

Comment: Oh. I see. Not that I have any money to buy any swag. I just wanted to see what the deal with the black shirt Eric mentioned... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila The shirt Eric is talking about is a generic "Stack Exchange" shirt. :) I believe the Math.SE ones are only in white.

Comment: Oh. Well, I might remember to wear it when I get my masters degree. The folks from the department administration gave me the stinkeye when I wore a black shirt for my B.Sc. ceremony. But then again, they only gave me the least amount of money they could... :-P

Comment: @Asaf: I wear mine regularly, but it is generally under layers and layers of other stuff nowadays. (-4 degrees centigrade this morning.) (-looks under sweater- hey! I'm wearing the TeX one today.)

Comment: @Willie: The only white item of clothing I wear is socks... :-)

Comment: Where is my swag :)

Comment: _+1_ for _swag_!

Answer (score 13):

I got a neat 12 oz math.stackexchange.com mug when I became a mod, but after that, nothing. I don't know if the devs or SE staff get any compensation (other than god-like powers on all sites).

Comment: Maybe you can lend that mug to Robert next time you see him...

Comment: I got that without being a moderator. Do I get a second mug if I become a moderator? If so, can I [stack]exchange it for a beer stein or some pens? I really liked the pen in the care package.

Comment: Inever got the mug :-(

Comment: @Mariano: Didn't you get the care package they sent the Top 40 list?

Comment: My 12oz mug is about a quarter-inch too tall to fit under the office coffee machine =( I just keep it around for decoration. And for tea.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That's strange. Even I did get the mug (and more importantly, the bubble wrap).

Comment: @Phira: I forgot; the bubble wrap was also appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Nobody has paid me anything yet.

Comment: Are you a moderator?

Comment: Looks to me like you've got nearly 70,000 in the bank.

Comment: With that and a couple of dollars I can buy a cup of coffee.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: What type of coffee do you like? Hazelnut? Black? Try some white tea.

Comment: white tea is amazing -- it has to be said